# NullPointerException loading resource in IntelliJ JavaFX Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, nullpointerexception

I'm working / learning on a JavaFX program using IntelliJ and Gradle. As part of it, I'm trying to load in a JSON file, but I keep getting a NullPointerException.

If I understand correctly, IntelliJ marks src -> main -> java as the Java source root, and src -> main -> resources as the resources root. Code goes in to java, other files go into resources. So I've put my JSON file in the resources file, and matched the directory structure there to the package structure where the class is trying to load the resource. The project structure looks like this:

```
C:.
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───gmail
│   │           └───jakesaddress
│   │               └───jgametest
│   │                   ├───map
│   │                   └───ui
│   └───resources
│       └───com
│           └───gmail
│               └───jakesaddress
│                   └───jgametest
│                       └───map
└───test
    ├───java
    └───resources
```

The code I'm using to try and load the file is (I've tried both with the same result):

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("map.json");
  -- or --
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/gmail/jakesaddress/jgametest/map/map.json");
```

The class I'm loading it from is:

```
com.gmail.jakesaddress.jgametest.map.Map
```

From what I've read so far, I believe I also needed two other bits of config. In IntelliJ, I needed to add JSON to the "Resource patterns" list in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler, it it now reads like this:

```
!?*.java;!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.clj;!?*.aj;?*.json
```

I'm running this via the Gradle application run task, and if I understand correctly, Gradle may also be defining resources differently to IntelliJ, so I needed the following in my build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/main/java'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/main/resources'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working, and I'm not sure where to look next. Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Resource patterns IDE settings have no effect on Gradle projects. If the issue occurs when building from the command line as well, it has nothing to do with IntelliJ IDEA too.

Comment: I had that feeling as well, but as nothing else seemed to work, I figured I'd give it a try. I've now tried from the command line with "gradle run" in my project dir (had to learn how to set org.gradle.java.home on the way), and get the same result.  So not an IntelliJ issue.

Comment: You need to look into the JAR or WAR and find whether the resource is really there under `/com/gmail/jakesaddress/jgametest/map/map.json`. Clearly it isn't. NB As you are using `getClassLoader()` a path relative to the current class won't work.

Comment: I've had a similar thought, but I can't find the jar under build when I run the application -> run task.  If I do the build -> jar task, the resulting jar does have the resource in it right next to the class files, but in my learning thus far, I'm not sure how to run a standalone JavaFX jar, so I can't test that.

Comment: More research, and I've downloaded the JavaFX SDK, dumped it in my Java folder, and passed --module-path and --add-modules to the java command line; now getting an error loading the json-simple libraries (I think). I thought this was all handled by the build.gradle?  So it shouldn't change whether running from IDE or command line, it's still Gradle building it?  At any rate, working through that now....

Answer (score 0):

Rereading the docs for getResourceAsStream led me to try the full path, but without the leading "/", like so:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/gmail/jakesaddress/jgametest/map/map.json");
```

This seems to work; it's reading values from the json file now.